# How to ignore duplicates during bulk inserts?

Tags: postgresql, insert, postgresql-9.3, duplication, upsert

In Postgres 9.3.5, I'm importing records from an external source where duplicates are VERY rare, but they do happen. Given a `readings` table with a **unique** compound key on `(real_time_device_id, recorded_at)`, the following will fail once in a blue moon:

```
INSERT INTO readings (real_time_device_id, recorded_at, duration) VALUES
  ('150', TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2014-11-01 23:06:33 -0700', 10.0),
  ... many more records ...
  ('150', TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2014-11-01 23:06:43 -0700', 10.0);
```

(FWIW, the above fails 'properly' with a duplicate key violation.)

I know that handling exceptions is expensive, but as I said, duplicate entries are very rare. So to keep the code simple, I followed an example given in [Optimal way to ignore duplicate inserts?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30499/optimal-way-to-ignore-duplicate-inserts):

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO readings (real_time_device_id, recorded_at, duration) VALUES
      ('150', TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2014-11-01 23:06:33 -0700', 10.0),
      ... many more records ...
      ('150', TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2014-11-01 23:06:43 -0700', 10.0);
EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
  -- silently ignore inserts
END;
```

The above gets two errors:

```
psql:sketches/t15.sql:11: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INSERT"
LINE 2:         INSERT INTO readings (real_time_device_id, recorded_...
                ^
psql:sketches/t15.sql:14: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "EXCEPTION"
LINE 1: EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
        ^
```

Can anyone set me straight on the correct syntax?  Or is my error deeper than mere syntax?  (For example, will all of the INSERTs be ignored if there is a single duplicate?)

Generally, what's a good way to do bulk inserts where very few (< .1%) are duplicates?

Comment: The code you use above is meant to be the body of a `pl/pgsql` function.  You can either create a real function using it, or use a `DO` block.  However, be careful, this way you won't silently get over the failing row.  The whole thing won't throw an error but you won't have any lines inserted, either.

Comment: @dezso - thanks for the clarification.  I'm considering doing a join on an immediate table with the incumbent table to see if there's any overlap, and if there's no overlamp, do the bulk insert. If there is overlap, I'll check / insert records one by one.

Comment: You can do also the following: insert your data into a staging table (without a unique constraint), remove the duplicates and insert the remainder into the final table.  Depending on some factors (like the amount of data) this may be better or worse performance-wise than the approach in your comment.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this assumes that any duplicates are in the insert statement. Duplicates are more likely between a record already in the table and a newly inserted record.  (I'm inserting ~250K records in batches of 500 each.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are **3 possible kinds of duplicates**:

1. Duplicates within the rows of the bulk insert. That's **your** immediate cause for the exception.
2. Duplicates between inserted rows and existing rows.
3. Duplicates between inserted rows and concurrently inserted / updated rows from other transactions.

(Assuming no overlapping rows are ever *deleted* concurrently, which would introduce new challenges.)

**1. and 2.** can be fixed easily. But you really need to **define exactly** how to solve conflicts. Which row is to be picked?

```
INSERT INTO readings (real_time_device_id, recorded_at, duration)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (real_time_device_id, recorded_at)  -- solves 1.
       i.real_time_device_id, i.recorded_at, i.dur
FROM  (
   VALUES
     ('150', TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2014-11-01 23:06:33 -0700', 10.0)
   , ('150', TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2014-11-01 23:06:43 -0700', 10.0)
   ) i (real_time_device_id, recorded_at, dur)
LEFT   JOIN readings r1 USING (real_time_device_id, recorded_at)
WHERE  r1.real_time_device_id IS NULL                  -- solves 2.
```

I am picking an arbitrary row from each set of dupes with `DISTINCT ON`. You may want to define deterministically instead:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

**3.** is more tricky - but hopefully not applicable to your case ...

If it applies after all, consider this:

- [How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42217872/939860)

To insert ~250K rows, it would be much more efficient to `COPY` the lot to a temp table (or as much as you can easily store in RAM and process without spilling to disk) and proceed from there.

If that's a large part of the table, it might pay to drop indexes you don't need for the duration of the update and create them afterwards ...

- [Getting error while importing large data through csv](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/38839/getting-error-while-importing-large-data-through-csv/38840#38840)
- [Call UPSERT function multiple times to different inputs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82120/call-upsert-function-multiple-times-to-different-inputs/82125#82125)
- [How to update selected rows with values from a CSV file in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8910810/939860)

Comment: Great answer -- thanks!  Elegant use of `LEFT JOIN .. WHERE .. IS NULL`.  Re: resolving duplicates: in this application, if there are two simultaneous readings, it doesn't matter which I choose.  Re: concurrent writes: Mercifully, I'm the sole writer to the table (so far).  Re: COPY: I'll investigate.