# Postgres: Insert distinct values from one table into another table with constrains in place

Tags: postgresql, constraint, distinct

I'm trying to insert data from one PostgreSQL 9.3 table to another while removing duplicate entries.

I have two tables containing email addresses.

The main table contains emails and a tag for each email address. The combination `(email, tag)` must be unique, and for this there is a constraint `Unique(email, tag)` on it.

The second table get created on the fly from text files which contain only the email address. There are many duplicates there.

I need to import the data from the temp table into the main one without breaking the constraint above. For a certain file containing email addresses the tag is constant.

Table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE emails (   
  email character varying(128),
  tag bigint,
  CONSTRAINT "unique-tag-email" UNIQUE (email, tag) )
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE emails_temp (email character varying(128)
```

Here is my query:

```
insert into emails(tag,email) 
select 
 655,t.email 
from 
 emails_temp as t 
where 
 not exists ( select email from emails where email = t.email )
```

Note: 655 is just a tag of a certain group of email addresses.

This is the error I get:

> ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint
>   "unique-tag-email" SQL state: 23505 Detail: Key (email,
>   tag)=(user@hotmail.com, 655) already exists.

There are indeed, two email addresses user@hotmail.com in the file.

Useless to say, because of this error, there is nothing added in the main table (email).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong. You are getting what you coded. 1st There is a unique key. 2nd The where condition in the correlated query select results that violate the unique key....Since `user@hotmail.com, 655` already exists, the constraint is violated and therefore the DML won't succeed

Comment: well, to insert distinct values you may want to try _selecting_ distinct values: `insert ... select distinct 655, t.email ...`

Comment: Thanks for the comments.However, I was under the assumption that the clause **where 
 not exists ( select email from emails where email = t.email )** is there exactly to prevent email addresses to be duplicated.


**Select distinct** doesn't work either. I get the same error as before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are **3** possible kinds of duplicates:

1. Duplicates within the rows of the bulk insert.
2. Duplicates between inserted rows and existing rows.
3. Duplicates between inserted rows and concurrently inserted / updated rows from other transactions.

Just like I explained in this closely related answer:

- [Using EXCEPTION to ignore duplicates during bulk inserts](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84058/using-exception-to-ignore-duplicates-during-bulk-inserts/84143#84143)

But things have become easier for ***2.*** and  ***3.*** since Postgres 9.5 introduced UPSERT (`INSERT .. ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`).

```
INSERT INTO emails(tag,email)
SELECT DISTINCT 655, email
FROM   emails_temp
ON CONFLICT (email) DO NOTHING;
```

If your duplicates only stem from duplicate entries in the source (***1.***), like you indicated, then all you need is `DISTINCT`. Works in any version of Postgres:

```
INSERT INTO emails(tag,email)
SELECT DISTINCT 655, email
FROM   emails_temp;
```

Comment: Erwin, thanks for the idea. I read about it too, but I can't upgrade to PSQL 9.5. I am stuck with 9.3 for some other reasons which I can't control.

Comment: @Sorin: Seems like all you need is `DISTINCT`, really. I added a bit above.

Comment: For previous versions without `ON CONFLICT`: `INSERT INTO emails (tag,email) SELECT DISTINCT 655, email
FROM emails_temp EXCEPT SELECT tag, email FROM emails WHERE tag = 655 ;`